# Class RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware

I have created a custom midddleware using the following command

```
php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated
```

This is my middlware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App;

class RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!App::environment(['production'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user->password_updated_at) {
            return redirect()->route('profile.password.edit')->with([
                'message' => 'Please update your password to proceed',
                'alertType' => 'warning',
            ]);
        }
        if (Carbon::now()->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($user->password_updated_at)) > 90) {
            return redirect()->route('profile.password.edit')->with([
                'message' => 'Your password has expired! Please update your password to proceed',
                'alertType' => 'warning',
            ]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I would like to use this middleware in the constructor of my controllers like following

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated');
}
```

When, I do that I get a `ReflectionException (-1)` that says

```
Class RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated does not exist
```

Here's the error in detail

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\gmi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate a concrete instance of the given type.
     *
     * @param  string  $concrete
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
     */
    public function build($concrete)
    {
        // If the concrete type is actually a Closure, we will just execute it and
        // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
        // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
        if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
            return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
        }

        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

        // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
        // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
        // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
        if (! $reflector->isInstantiable()) {
            return $this->notInstantiable($concrete);
        }

        $this->buildStack[] = $concrete;

        $constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

        // If there are no constructors, that means there are no dependencies then
        // we can just resolve the instances of the objects right away, without
        // resolving any other types or dependencies out of these containers.
        if (is_null($constructor)) {
            array_pop($this->buildStack);

            return new $concrete;
        }
```

I an using this midddleware in other Laravel (v5.4, v5.6) projects in the same way which are working without any issues. But it's not working in the current version (v5.8). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated your middleware in `app > Http > Kernal.php` .......inside `protected $routeMiddleware = [ ...... ] ` ?

Comment: No man. I didn't. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i can see that you haven't registered your `middleware class` in `app\Http\Kernel.php`. registering a middleware is very simple just like below:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
   'middle_name' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfPasswordNotUpdated::class,
]
```